# How to compare a char with a null?

Tags: java, null

I must compare if a char is `null`. I think about that (char is the name of my variable):

```
Character.toString(sauv).equals(null)
OR
Character.toString(sauv) == null
OR
char.equals(null)
OR
char == null
```

But it didn't work. How could I compare char with `null`?

I checked my method with a char table with size 4 and with 3 elements in the table. For example: `{1,2,3, }`

My method must check that I changed a char in this table, otherwise that `null`. The changed character must be returned.

Comment: A `char` cannot be `null`.  Do you mean `'\0'`?

Comment: Could you show us how you assign null to your char?

Comment: What's the datatype of your char variable. If it's Character you can do if(myChar == null) otherwise you can't with a primitive type (primitive only have a default value, but can't be null as they are not reference type).

Comment: Primitives in general _cannot_ be null, so this would always be false in any event.

Comment: As mentioned previously a `char` cannot be `null`.  Additionally, a variable cannot be named `char` (it's a reserved keyword, and will show up as a compile error).

Comment: I checked my method with a char table with size 4 and with 3 elements in the table )

for example : {1,2,3, } My method must check that I change a char in this table otherwise that null . The changed character must be return.

Comment: Default values for primitive types: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: if(char != '\u0000') this should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

char cannot be null.
try using '\0'. this might help yu

Comment: Ughhhh the text language

Comment: Please articulate your response in a way becoming of someone teaching others.

Comment: `\0` is not a valid escape sequence in Java.

Comment: Sorry . It didn't work. How about the length attribut ? a null char must have a length == 0 ?

Comment: for example : char c ; c == '\0'

Comment: @rgettman I can't find it in the JLS but it works with Oracle's JDK without any error or warning